# Aggregate on measure in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I have some measures created, with an example table such as:

| Fruit | Fruit Measure | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | sweetness | 90 |
| banana | sweetness | 80 |
| banana | tartness | 15 |
| banana | tartness | 20 |
| peach | sweetness | 70 |
| peach | sweetness | 65 |
| peach | tartness | 35 |
| peach | tartness | 40 |
| apple | sweetness | 65 |
| apple | sweetness | 60 |
| apple | tartness | 30 |
| apple | tartness | 25 |
| kiwi | sweetness | 20 |
| kiwi | sweetness | 15 |
| kiwi | tartness | 85 |
| kiwi | tartness | 90 |

etc etc.

**[edit] for clarification:**

Basically, I have a category `Fruit` with an associated `Fruit Measure`, and I have created the following measures to get a summation of the multiple sweetness/tartness values for each fruit. I also take the percentage of column total (since the sweetness/tartness values are on a different scale and not inherently comparable). As an example: `%ColTotal = bananaSweetness/TotalFruitSweetness => 170/(170 + 135 + 125 + 35) = .3656`, as follows:

```
SumPerFruit =
SUMX ( VALUES ( Table[Fruit Measure] ), CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table[Value] ) ) )
```

```
PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit =
DIVIDE (
    [SumPerFruit],
    SUMX (
        VALUES ( Table[Fruit Measure] ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table[Value] ), ALLSELECTED ( table[Fruit] ) )
    )
)
```

This results with calculations like the following :

| Fruit | Fruit Measure | SumPerFruit | PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| banana | sweetness | 170 | .3656 |
| banana | tartness | 55 | .1029 |
| peach | sweetness | 135 | .2903 |
| peach | tartness | 75 | .2206 |
| apple | sweetness | 125 | .2688 |
| apple | tartness | 55 | .1618 |
| kiwi | sweetness | 35 | .0753 |
| kiwi | tartness | 175 | .5147 |

**[EDIT] for more clarification on SummaryFruitMeasure**

Now, the above measures just combine the multiple sweetness/tartness values for each fruit into two values for every fruit-- one for tart, and one for sweet. Ideally, I just want to have one numerical average value that can summarize both the sweetness/tartness values for a fruit. Thus, I want to just take an average like the following:

```
BananaSummaryMeasure = (BananaTartness + BananaSweetness)/2 => (.3656 + .1029)/2
```

so I tried to get the average of `PercentageofColtotal_SumPerFruit` for every fruit as follows:

```
SummaryFruitMeasure =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Table[Fruit] ),
    CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( SUM ( Table[PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit] ), 2 ) )
)
```

with the intended result of:

| Fruit | SummaryFruitMeasure |
| --- | --- |
| banana | .23425 |
| peach | .255545 |
| apple | .2153 |
| kiwi | .295 |

However, I get an error with the `SUM(Table[PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit])` section as follows:

> Column `PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit` in table "Table" cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

So I'm assuming that it can't be used in this expression because it's a measure. How do I get around this? Should I be using [`SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax) or something like that? I'm not sure if its possible to aggregate further on `PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit`?

Also, I have to use measures because the actual data would be filtered on.

**[edit]** I've also looked into something like [this](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/nested-grouping-using-groupby-vs-summarize/#code4) but that results in a table, and I want a measure at the end of this..

Comment: also be careful: ALLSELECTED should not be used in measure called from iterators in other measures. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-allselected/

Comment: What is `SummaryFruitMesure` intended to represent? How is it interpreted?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I've added some clarifications, thanks

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, doesn't SUMX(Table, [PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit]) do it for you? I just skimmed at your question, so it's possible that I'm missing its point :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be 2 approaches, depending on the granularity of your data. They can be visualised like this. The first measure (Measure one) always shows your desired result, regardless, if you put Fruit Measure in the visual or not. The second one does not and allows you to see it at the fruit level, as well as at the measurement level.

[image]

```
Measure one =
CALCULATE (
    DIVIDE (
        SUMX (
            VALUES ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] ),
            DIVIDE (
                CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ) ),
                CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ), ALLSELECTED ( Fruit[Fruit] ) )
            )
        ),
        COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] ) )
    ),
    ALLSELECTED ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] )
)
```

---

```
Measure two =
DIVIDE (
    SUMX (
        VALUES ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] ),
        DIVIDE (
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ) ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ), ALLSELECTED ( Fruit[Fruit] ) )
        )
    ),
    COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] ) )
)
```

I decided to use `COUNTROWS()` (instead of simple division by 2) , to make it work with any number of `Fruit Measure` values.

In the second measure, `VALUES ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] )` could be put in a variable, as it's used twice, to make it look less repetitive.

My recommendation would be to go with something like `Measure two`, as it's more flexible (and quite elegant), but it depends on you reporting requirements.

**EDIT**

Actually, `Measure two` is unnecessarily convoluted. It should be simplified like this:

```
Measure three =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] ),
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ) ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ), ALLSELECTED ( Fruit[Fruit] ) )
    )
)
```

Apologies for that.

[image]

And just to answer your question about `SUM(Table[PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit])` giving an error, you can use measures in SUMX, e.g. `SUMX(Table, [PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit])`. Note, I'm not refering to correctness of the result of this operation in this context.

**EDIT2**

Here is another take on `Measure one` based on the comment. This time it calculates values based on all fruit, regardless of slicer selection / filtering.

```
Measure one = 
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX (
        VALUES ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] ),
        DIVIDE (
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ) ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( Fruit[Value] ), ALL ( Fruit[Fruit] ) )
        )
    ),
    ALL ( Fruit[Fruit Measure] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, took some time to process & understand. In this case, `MeasureOne` is definitely the one that matches what I need more, but I'll have to modify a bit because I need to be able to visually filter on including/excluding certain fruits without re-calculating the values.

Comment: Thanks for the reward. Let me modify my answer (and Measure one) to show the sames values regardless of filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Your DAX is unnecessarily complicated and it's tripping you up. The particular error is that you cannot use SUM on anything except a table column (measures are not columns).

I'd recommend this instead:

```
SumValue = SUM ( Table[Value] )
```

```
PercentOfTotal =
    DIVIDE (
        [SumValue],
        CALCULATE ( [SumValue], ALLSELECTED ( Table ) )
    )
```

Using these two should work whether you break out into sweet/tart or not.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I am writing the DAX that way is because the tartness/sweetness values are on a different scale and so I convert to a percentage of column total with `PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit` column to make them comparable. I know that I cannot `SUM` a measure, but was hoping there was some way to get around that with `SUMMARIZE` etc as I wanted to calculate an average value for each fruit on the `PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit` column

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarize` in measures:

```
SummaryFruitMeasure =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE(
       Table, 
       Table[Fruit],
       Table[Fruit Measure],
       "PercentageTotal", [PercentageofColTotal_SumPerFruit]
    ),
    DIVIDE ( SUM ( [PercentageTotal] ), 2 )
)
```